# Find elasticsearch indices with no aliases

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch cluster whose indices I need to investigate.  Specifically, I want to find all indices that do not have aliases.

Is this even possible?  If so, how?

(Using `sense` notation for this question.)

I know I can get all indices with their aliases, even if the alias field is empty:

```
GET _aliases
```

And I know I can get all indices that have aliases:

```
GET /*/_alias/*
```

But can I get all indices *without* aliases?

Clearly, I can just get all indices, and then use some tool like `awk` or whatever to do the work for me, but my naïve guess is that it's most efficient for elasticsearch to do all this work at once.

Comment: You can try: GET _cat/indices?v

Comment: Does this endpoint return the alias names of the indices as well? @Monicka
It might have changed on the newer version, but i don't seem to get them in my response.

Comment: I get this columns: health,status,index,pri,rep, docs.count, docs.deleted store.size, pri.store.size. I have Elasticsearch 2.x version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: There is no easy api for you to find out which indices have not been linked to an alias.

**Long answer**: You could try the '_cluster/state' endpoint like this:

```
GET _cluster/state?filter_path=metadata.indices.test.aliases
```

Where *test* is the name of your index. It gives the following result:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "indices": {
      "test": {
        "aliases": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now if I try it with an index that is actually linked:

```
GET _cluster/state?filter_path=metadata.indices.test_with_alias.aliases
```

I get the following result:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "indices": {
      "test_with_alias": {
        "aliases": [
          "new_alias"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's not the prettiest way to do this, but it's possible :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!! This is so much easier than the next best solution I'd fumbled into.

Answer (score 0):

This shell script will help you

```
#!/bin/bash
ES="https://localhost:9316"
INDICES=`curl -XGET ${ES}/_cat/indices -s --insecure | awk '{print $3}'`
META=`curl -XGET "${ES}/_cluster/state?filter_path=metadata.indices.*.aliases" -s --insecure`
echo ${#META}
for INDEX in $INDICES
do
  if [[ ${INDEX} != \.* ]]
  then
    RES=`jq ".metadata.indices.${INDEX}.aliases" <<< ${META}`
    if [[ ${#RES} == 2 ]]
    then
      RES="NOALIAS"
    fi
    echo ${INDEX} $RES
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine this as follows via the Java REST High Level Client:

```
val indexResponse = client.indices().get(GetIndexRequest("*"), RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
val aliases = indexResponse.aliases
```

`aliases` is of type `Map<String, List<AliasMetadata>>`. Every Map entry with a empty list (without alias metadata) is a index without an alias.

With this in mind, here's what you need to do to get all the indices without aliases.

```
val indicesWithoutAliases = indexResponse.aliases.filterValues { it.isEmpty() }
```